# How do I parse a csv file to find the "fails" in the file which is on column 2 and find the average of column 7

Tags: bash, csv, average

```
grep "false" $1 | cut -d ',' -f2,7
```

this is as far as I got. with this I can get all the false errors and their respond time. But I am having a hard time finding the average out of all the respond time's combine.

Comment: do you need an average value for each line (columns 2 and 7) or the average value for the whole csv file?

Comment: consider reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update the question with more details

Comment: Thank you all for responding. Column 2 got all the respond time, Column 7 says if it was an error "false". I want to calculate the average of column 2. I want to get the average response time of all the false errors.

Comment: If you refine the question to include sample input and expected output, as well as the clarifications you've made in the above comments and the comments of my answer, I'll give this question a +1. Please accept my answer if it solves your issue and/or give it a +1 if it is helpful to you overall. Otherwise, please comment as to how it does not address your question, providing clarifying information. (See Kent's comment above; think about how you can help us help you.)

Comment: A potential issue and something to clarify is if the CSV file being used includes escape sequences. This will occur if fields in the CSV contain either commas or newlines. If so, they need to be escaped to be valid CSV. CSV escaping working by placing values in double quotes, allowing comma and newlines used for data to be separated from field delimiters. CSV escaping may be enabled for other reasons. The important part - If the file contains CSV escapes, solutions involving unix tools like `cut` and `awk` will not work correctly. Instead it is necessary to switch to CSV aware tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not fully clear what you're trying to do, but if you're looking for the arithmetic mean of all second comma-delimited fields ("columns") where the seventh field is `false` then here's an answer using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F ',' '$7 == "false" { f++; sum += $2 } END { print sum / f }' "$@"
```

This sets the field separator to be `,` and then parses only lines whose seventh (comma-delimited) field is exactly `false` (also consider `tolower($7) == "false"`), incrementing a counter (`f`) and adding the second column to a `sum` variable. After running through all lines of all input files, the script prints the arithmetic mean by dividing the sum by the number of rows it keyed on. The trailing `"$@"` will send each argument to your shell script as a file for this `awk` command.

A note on fields: `awk` is one-indexed, but `0` often has a special value. `$0` is the whole line, `$1` is the first field, and so on. `awk` is pretty flexible, so you can also do things like `$i` to refer to the field represented by a variable `i`, including things like `$(NF-1)` to refer to the contents of the field before the last field of the line.

**Non-delimiting commas:**
If your data might have quoted values with commas in them, or escaped commas, the field calculation in `awk` (or in `cut`) won't work. A proper CSV parser (requiring a more complete language than `bash` plus extras like `awk`, `sed`, or `cut`) would be preferable to making your own. Alternatively, if you control the format, you can consider a different delimiter such as <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the dedicated ASCII Record Separator character (RS, a.k.a. `U+001E`, Information Separator Two, which you can enter in bash as `$'\x1e'` and in `awk` (and most other languages) as `"\x1e"`).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. You understand what I am trying to do but this script wont work. The reason is because it gets the average of column 2 and 7 combine. While column 7 is where you find the 'false'. I dont need the average of column 7, I am trying to get the average of column 2

Comment: Do you mean the average of all rows’ column 2 where column 7 is `false`?

Comment: Yes the average of all rows in column 2

Comment: @spanglyleek – I've updated my answer to account for my new understanding of your question, but I still implore you to update the question (see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60046176/519360#comment106198966_60046176)).

Comment: How would I parse the whole csv file to print the total amount of requests ex: 100 request, 90 passed and the average response time is #. 10 fail and average response time is #.

Comment: `awk` stores the number of lines it has read (the "number of records") in `NR`. You could add that to the `print` command, e.g. `printf "%d request, %d passed, average response time %.1f\n", NR, NR - f, sum / f` (I'm guessing about what means what since you haven't explained any of it, such as `NR - f` to get the number of lines that did _not_ have `$7 == "false"`, but note that the average is just of the false lines).

Comment: Thank you Adam, you have been great help. I am still a bit confuse on how "%d" works on the script. Could you explain how does "%d" gets its input. And I want to add the the print command. I would like the script to output the # of fails that happen out of all the lines. would it be something like " printf "%d request, %d passed, average response time %.1f\n, %d failed ", NR, NR - f, sum / f, f - NR" does that makes sense?

Comment: and for wanting the average for the "passed" lines instead of the "fail" lines. how should I changed the "sum / f" ?

Comment: [`printf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) in `awk` works as it does in almost any language: it uses a template where each percent character positionally corresponds to the arguments that follow it. `printf "a=%d b=%d c=%.1f\n", a, b, c` will print `a` and `b` as **d**ecimal integers and `c` as a **f**loating point value with precision to the tenths. The average for "passed" lines would have to be calculated from their sum in a new stanza, `$7 != "false" { t++; true_sum += $2 }` and then at the `END` you can use `true_sum / t`

Comment: `awk -F ',' '$7 == "true" { f++; true_sum += $2 } END { printf "number of requests: %d\n passed: %d\n average response time %.2f\n failed %d\n\n", NR, f, true_sum / f, NR -f }' "$@" ` .   thank you for the help Adam. Here is my final script that meets all the requirements I was aiming for.